# Google chrome command line switches for permission

Tags: google-chrome

How do I turn off the permission in google chrome through command line action?

I try to run headless google chrome through xvfb and I need to access an url that download multiple files. After long waiting the file that downloaded only one and that's because the other file prevented by google chrome permission.

The option that I think about is to turn of the permission or make the default permission for download to "allow on this site".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After do some test to overcome the google chrome permission is by create a new tab so if want to download 5 items we need to create a code that will open the new tab 5 times and manage each of the tab according to your URL. Because I use javascript use `window.open()` and `window.close()` will do the trick.